# what is the meaning of these in an academic paper?

Tags: meaning

I was searching some academic publishes on a site. And their search result are like below.

I want to know what the numbers means. For example what is the published date ? What does 2010 Oct;(5):522-5. Epub 2010 Jun 2 mean ?

Sildenafil in the management of the failing Fontan circulation.

Reinhardt Z, Uzun O, Bhole V, Ofoe V, Wilson D, Onuzo O, Wright JG, Stumper O.

Cardiol Young. 2010 Oct;20(5):522-5. Epub 2010 Jun 2.

---

Oral sildenafil for persistent pulmonary hypertension early after congenital cardiac surgery in children.

Nemoto S, Sasaki T, Ozawa H, Katsumata T, Kishi K, Okumura K, Mori Y, Umegaki O.

**Eur J Cardiothorac Surg. 2010 Jul;38(1):71-7. Epub 2010 Mar 4.**

Free Article

Comment: [This](http://www.niso.org/apps/group_public/download.php/6545/Bibliographic%20References.pdf)

Comment: 2010: published in the year 2010; 
Oct: published in the month October of the given year; 
(5): issue number 5 in that year; 
522-5: page 522 to 525 in that issue; 
Epub: electronically published (i.e. online) since 
2010 Jun 2: 2nd of June of year 2010; 
http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S1047951110000648

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the date it was published in the journal and **epub** the date it was available electronically on the journals website. In the  days when it took months for papers to be typeset and printed the journals would also list a "received" date.

The exact date something was publically available is important for priority and especially these days for patent prior art.